# Assert database error on DBT model on Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, dbt

since today we are having this error, the DBT/SQL was not touched I'm receiving errors in many processes with this same message.
A full refresh on DBT clears it, but when the first incremental runs, it starts to fail again with the same error, "context" is not helping, I ran the query manually and had no trouble at all.
The only change I saw was a Redshift automatic update with maintenance, but can't rollback, or don't know how.

```
20:26:44 | 
20:26:44 | 1 of 1 START incremental model xxxxxx......... [RUN]
20:26:51 | 1 of 1 ERROR creating incremental model xxxxxx [ERROR in 6.44s]
20:26:51 | 
20:26:51 | Finished running 1 incremental model in 8.55s.

Completed with 1 error and 0 warnings:

Database Error in model xxxxx (models/xxxxx.sql)
  Assert
  DETAIL:  
    -----------------------------------------------
    error:  Assert
    code:      1000
    context:   size >= 0 - size=-2, 0=0. 
    query:     62706875
    location:  tbl_trans.cpp:867
    process:   padbmaster [pid=70356]
    -----------------------------------------------
  compiled SQL at target/run/xxxxx/xxxxx.sql

Done. PASS=0 WARN=0 ERROR=1 SKIP=0 TOTAL=1
```

DBT makes a query, a delete and a insert.
I manually created a temp table with the same SQL query and inserted into the table without any problems. So is not a data type issue as far as I can think about it.
Any idea of what can be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's a Redshift issue rollbacked to 1.0.38094 and everything works again